# Generate random int with specified upper-bound (0 - n) without using / or %

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, bit-manipulation

roommate went to an interview and got this one:

**Rules:**

permitted to use rand();

RAND_MAX = 32 767;

no use of division or modulo;

**TODO:**
Write a function that takes one int parameter and returns
int in range 0 - parameter.

Head hurts, can't sleep. Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `int n; while((n = rand()) > parameter); return n;` (or `>=`, depends on whether the bound shall be in- or exclusive).

Comment: is the parameter static? if so you could make a lookup table of RAND_MAX entries that only contains values from 0 to parameter

Comment: @DanielFisher This does not satisfy the specification for `parameter > RAND_MAX` (and, say, 32-bit ints).

Comment: @Frankie Is there any more you could elaborate on this? Sometimes interviewers will add more restrictions as the interviewee provides more detailed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my public domain [randlib](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib), I do it with
no floating point, no division, no multiplication, just bitmasking and rejection sampling, like this:

```
int ojr_rand(ojr_generator *g, int limit) {
    int v, m = limit - 1;

    m |= m >> 1;
    m |= m >> 2;
    m |= m >> 4;
    m |= m >> 8; // m is smallest ((power of 2) - 1) > limit

    do {
            v = m & NEXT16(g);  // 16-bit random number
    } while (v >= limit);
    return v;
}
```

In the worst case (limit is power of two plus one), this can reject close to 50% of the generated numbers, but it's still faster than division or floating math with most fast RNGs, and in the general case it's much faster. Also, unlike the floating point math or mod, it is *exact*, meaning if you ask for a limit of 3, you get values 0, 1, and 2 with exactly equal probability, not just approximately equal.

Answer (score 4):

Few possibilities:

- the range transposition approach: `int r = rand() * 0.00003051855095 * n;`
- the "shuffle sort" approach: `int r; do { r = random(); } while (r >= n);`
- the BSD approach: `uint32_t r = arc4random_uniform(n);`

Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Multiply by decimal can be thought of as division.

Comment: @ChrisCM It can be "though of" as, but it isn't - it's multiplication.

Comment: It is undeniably not within the spirit of the question.

Comment: What you call the "shuffle sort" approach is technically called "rejection sampling", and is the only way to get the exactly correct answer. All the other methods give only an approximately equal distribution (though good enough for all but the most demanding uses).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I see the limitations of the first method, but how `arc4random_uniform()` is not **uniform** enough?

Comment: Actually, arc4random_uniform() claims to be correct, so it must be implemented by some form of rejection sampling.

Answer (score 2):

If c++11 is allowed there is a random header provided that makes this trivial:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int Roll(int Max)
{
    if(Max>32767)
        Max=32767;
    std::random_device generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,Max);
    return distribution(generator);   
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << Roll(10) << std::endl
              << Roll(10) << std::endl
              << Roll(999999) << std::endl;
}
```

More details at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

This presumes that RAND_MAX is provided by your problem and not by the C standard of course you could use the provided constant, for details see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX

Answer (score 1):

```
do { r = random();} while (r >= max_rand);
```

At first I thought multiplying by a fraction would work but that could be considered cheating from a mathematical standpoint.

Answer (score -1):

```
int getRand(int max)
{
    int val = rand();

    while (val > max)
    {
        val -= max + 1;
    }

    return val;
}
```

This will obviously be off slightly by counting values <= `RAND_MAX % max` once more than everything else but `rand() % max` has the same problem so I assume this error to be acceptable (for values of `max` << `MAX_RAND` the error is insignificant).

Comment: This identical to using %, just slower.